# Android service's new thread error: Thread already started

Tags: android, service

There's broadcastReceiver receive boot message and set a alarmmanager.

It start a service every DELAY mins:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("org.jxdwinter.getMessageServcie");
 PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getService(arg0, 0, intent, 0);
 am = (AlarmManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), DELAY, pendingintent);
```

The service poll data from romate server in a new thread:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    this.getMessage.start();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
private class GetMessage extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
       ... ....
    }       
}
```

And when the app started, I can get the data at very first time and there's no 
error.

Then the service start again in DELAY mins , there's an error:Thread already started.

Why is happened? Pls help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: A `Thread` instance can only be started once

Comment: @fiddler How can I fix this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could just create a new instance of your thread each time you need it to run:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    new GetMessage().start();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is instance of GetMesdsage class you are using by any chance static? If yes,  do not doe this - initialize new one